# Long delay function call in python?

Tags: python, flask, operating-system

In python how to efficiently call another function after delay of long time (in days). I know we can use sleep function or threading.Timer, but someone told me that this will create new thread for each time timer function is called, So in a program where large no. of function calls of these type are made what is an efficient way without putting the all system resources (cpu) on checking time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using manual multi threading, why don't you consider using Async.io to do long running functions.

This approach is only available from Python 3.7+ but is more effective and efficient and requires less coding. Here is an [in depth tutorial](https://realpython.com/async-io-python/) on how to use it

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not processor intensive. It lets the processor idle.

According to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep), it suspends execution, so that means it is not processor intensive. A [busy wait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting) would be processor intensive.